# Can MEAN and LAMP stacks be used together?

Tags: lamp, mean, digital-ocean

Is it possible to run the two simultaneously serving different pages by different stacks?

I have found one person comment that it can be possible but the answer wasn't very specific. 
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/lamp-and-mean-stack-on-the-same-droplet

Has anyone done this before and can you post specifics?

Answer (score 0):

This might be better posted in [Super User](https://superuser.com/) or [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/) or even on DigitalOcean's forums if you're considering them as a specific Service Provider.

The short answer is **yes**, they can both be used together.

The long answer is **yes, but why**:

LAMP stands for Linux Apache MySQL and PHP (generally).

MEAN stands for MongoDB ExpressJS AngularJS and NodeJS.

Taking the server-centric approach to those stacks, the import parts are:

- Linux (Operating Systems)
- MongoDB / MySQL (Databases)
- Apache (HTTP Server)
- NodeJS/ExpressJS / PHP (Application Servers / Programming
  languages)

These are pretty much all separate software packages (processes and code) talking to each other in separate ways.

The only downside (since you ask for specifics) is around performance. Running two services on a single droplet, while possible, is not ideal in a cloud environment. Some of the benefits of the cloud and virtual machines (segmenting roles and processes into separate environments) heavily outweigh any gains ($5/mo) you'd get for running both on both servers.

That said, it's not uncommon to do so -- as there are lots of environments running all kinds of services on the same machine (virtual or not).